# Jena multiline string output

Tags: jena

is it possible to output turtle, with string that are multiline that is have jena keep the multi-line when outputing the result ?

I'm currently struggling to do so, i have properties that have multi-line text,  but jena keep outputing as one string, with  the escape in it i.e. "\n" all over

## Edit1

Found the following discussions (curious to know where it landed)

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201512.mbox/%3c56798EBD.9010807@apache.org%3e

I actually tried

```
ARQ.getContext().set(RIOT.multilineLiterals, true)
```

I the beginning of my code but with no success

```
 val program = for {

    _     <- IO { ARQ.getContext().set(RIOT.multilineLiterals, true)}

    model <- IO { ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() }
    

    _     <- IO { model.read("xxxxx.ttl")}

    _     <- IO { model.write(System.out, Lang.TURTLE.getName)}

  } yield ()
```

Note, the file contain string with multiline string.

Answer (score 1):

These ways to write work with context settings:

```
    RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, Lang.TURTLE);
```

```
    RDFWriter.create(model).lang(Lang.TURTLE).output(System.out);
```

Looking at the code, `model.write` involves backwards compatibility with setting writer properties (for RDF/XML).

It does not need to ignore global settings for other writers. This has been filed as a bug [JENA-2148](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-2148).